# Не получается войти на сайт через Гитхаб для парсера

Tags: python, requests, auth

Всем привет.

Нужна помощь,делаю **парсер сайта** `betsapi`,используя `requests` и beautifulsoup.

Для авторизации на сайте выбрал `гитхаб`,отправляю `POST` форму с данными

```
data = { 
         'commit' : u'Sign in',
         'login' : u'мойлогин',
         'password' : u'мой пароль',
         'authenticity_token': authtoken
    }
```

На гитхаб авторизуется ,проходит редирект на бетсапи,и повторно редиректит на бетсапи с кодом,выглядит так `betsapi.com/auth/?hauth.done=GitHub&amp;code=` ..........

Но в бетсапи не входит,выдает **500 ошибку сервера**
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нужно через инспектор браузера смотреть на запросы и повторить их. А так, 5хх это ошибка на сервере. Скорее всего, чего-то не передаете (параметр/заголовок/...). Точно не `betsapi.com/auth/?hauth.done=GitHub&code=` ?

Comment: я отправлял только **data** ,попробовал отправить **headers[user_agent]**.Вывел информацию о заголовках,но **user_agent** все равно нет

Comment: Нужно смотреть что отправляется в этом случае браузером и повторить. Заголовков больше чем `User-Agent`. Тыкаете F12 и смотрите на вкладке сети на тот запрос

Comment: Вы кукисы записали и передаете снова?